# Nextcloud - mass removal of collaborative tags from files

Tags: owncloud, nextcloud

due to an oversight in a flow-routine that was meant to tag certain folders on upload into the cloud, a huge amount of unwanted files were also tagged in the process. Now there are thousands upon thousands of files that have the wrong tag and need to be untagged. Neither doing this by hand nor reuploading with the correct flow-routine are really workable options. Is there a way to do the following:

1. Crawl through every entry in a folder
2. If its a file, untag it, if its a folder, don't

Everything I found about tags and NextCloud was concerning with handling them when they were uploaded, but never running over existing files in regards of tagging.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The cloud stores those data into the configured database. So you could simply remove the assigns from the db.

The assigns are stored in `oc_systemtag_object_mapping` while the tags itself are in `oc_systemtag`. If you found the ID of the tag to remove (let's say `4`), you could simply remove all assignments from the db:

```sql
DELETE FROM oc_systemtag_object_mapping WHERE systemtagid = 4;
```

If you would like to do this only for a specific folder, it's not even getting much more complicated. Files (including their folder structure!) are stored in `oc_filecache`, while  `oc_systemtag_object_mapping.objectid` references `oc_filecache.fileid`. So with some joining and `LIKE`ing, you could limit the rows to delete. If your tag is used for non-files, your condition should include `oc_systemtag_object_mapping.objecttype = 'files'`.